# mod_rewrite proxy RewriteRule not working

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite

I need to send all requests for the directory home/alphauser to backend/alphauser, but not requests to files inside the home/alphauser directory. For example:

```
http://home/alphauser            ->   http://backend/alphauser
http://home/alphauser/           ->   http://backend/alphauser
http://home/alphauser/icon.png   ->   http://home/alphauser/icon.png
http://home/alphauser/index.html ->   http://home/alphauser/index.html
```

I created an ".htaccess" file in the home/alphauser/ directory with the following:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^$ http://backend/alphauser [P]
```

mod_rewrite allows for access to files inside the home/alphauser/ directory as expected, but when the directory itself is requested either with or without the slash:

```
http://home/alphauser
http://home/alphauser/
```

..the browser (firefox) presents a file download popup that states:

```
You have chosen to open a file which
is a: httpd/unix-directory
```

The contents of the file is the proper html from backend/alphauser (which is the url pattern to a JSP) so the payload returned is correct. It seems as though apache is sending back this strange mime type of "httpd/unix-directory"

Help!

Comment: When you're sending it to mod_proxy with the `[P]` flag, do you have that setup correctly? I have a feeling it could be because of that. What do your logs say?

You can set the mimetype of a RewriteRule with the `T` flag e.g `[T=text/html]` but I don't think that's the best solution.

Comment: I'm using a ProxyPass directive in my apache2.conf already, so I would assume mod_proxy is setup correctly. The error.log has nothing, the access.log just shows a GET "/alphauser/" message with user agent info. I tried the same RewriteRule with [P,T=text/html] and the result was exactly the same.

Comment: I setup a RewriteLog directive in apache2.conf and set the log level to 9. The output seems normal: (1) `applying pattern ^$ to uri ''` (2) `rewrite -> backend/alphauser` (3) `forcing proxy-throughput with backend/alphauser` (4) `go-ahead with proxy request proxy:backend/alphauser [OK]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out the problem had nothing to do with mod_rewrite. My backend was not sending a ContentType header at all. Once I set it to populate the ContentType as `text/html` everything worked.

Answer (score -1):

Robert,

this seems to be weird to me

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^$ http://backend/alphauser [P]
```

the regular expression you made basically match anything fair enougth but it would not pass the URI to the backend.

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^/alphauser/$ http://backend/alphauser [P]
```

or

```
RewriteRule ^/$ http://backend/alphauser [P]
```

I am not 100 % sure how mod_rewrite behave in a .htaccess file

This would make much sense it my opinion, also you have to make sure you have `mod_proxy` and `mod_proxy_http` enabled or it won't work.

Comment: No luck.

mod_proxy is enabled because I'm already using ProxyPass and ProxyReversePass directives in apache2.conf.

Comment: Actually, the regular expression ^$ is intended to match no files and only the directory. I'm not interested in passing the URI - .htaccess is in the alphauser directory already - so the URI to pass is already known. I want requests to the /alphauser/ directory itself to pass through to a Servlet/JSP and other requests to proceed normally.

Comment: I appreciate your help. I tried your suggestion of `RewriteRule ^/$ http://backend/alphauser [P]` and it didn't pass through to the JSP for a url of `http://home/alphauser`. I looked at the rewrite logs and it showed: `applying pattern '^/$' to uri ''` which evaluates to false because the string doesn't start with `/`

Comment: oky then your `^$` was ok, do you have some access to the backend server ?